# How to Stitch json data into single line with Jq linux

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

I have a json stream that I want to make the output into single line with jq ( Linux )

###### From this

```
{
  "Icao": "800B0A",
  "Alt": 15375,
  "GAlt": 15278,
  "AltT": 0,
  "Lat": 10.579605,
  "Long": 76.506561,
  "Mlat": false,
  "Spd": 334.5,
  "Trak": 26.3,
  "Vsi": 832
}
{
  "Icao": "800463",
  "Alt": 3575,
  "GAlt": 3445,
  "AltT": 0,
  "Lat": 40.626663,
  "Long": -74.261963,
  "Mlat": false,
  "Spd": 274.4,
  "Trak": 316.2,
  "Vsi": 1472
}
```

###### To this

```
{"Icao":"A379CD","Alt":32025,"GAlt":32114,"InHg":30.0088577,"AltT":0,"Lat":38.335918,"Long":-104.720284,"Mlat":false,"Spd":403.0,"Trak":240.0,"Vsi":64},{"Icao":"345042","Alt":22850,"GAlt":22782,"InHg":29.8523617,"AltT":0,"Lat":39.655243,"Long":-8.845612,"Mlat":false,"Spd":308.5,"Trak":212.6,"Vsi":-1216},{"Icao":"40753D","Alt":37000,"GAlt":37050,"InHg":29.9704723,"AltT":0,"Lat":41.940674,"Long":-8.029816,"Mlat":false,"Spd":468.4,"Trak":190.2,"Vsi":-64},
```

Hope someone could hand a solution for the problem.

Comment: Is it intended that the input values and the output values do not match? If so, please explain how they change.

Comment: i've just used it for example .. the output from the stream produce somewhere around 100-200 objects per second.. so it is hard to capture the exact data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--compact-output` (or `-c`) option qill print each object in a single line, and the `--join-output` (or `-j`) option will omit the newline character between the objects.

```sh
jq -cj .
```

```json
{"Icao":"800B0A","Alt":15375,"GAlt":15278,"AltT":0,"Lat":10.579605,"Long":76.506561,"Mlat":false,"Spd":334.5,"Trak":26.3,"Vsi":832}{"Icao":"800463","Alt":3575,"GAlt":3445,"AltT":0,"Lat":40.626663,"Long":-74.261963,"Mlat":false,"Spd":274.4,"Trak":316.2,"Vsi":1472}
```

Note that while this is valid JSON, your desired output is not. It has commas after the objects. If you really need them, you can print a literal string like a comma using the `--raw-output` (or `-r`) option:

```sh
jq -cjr '.,","'
```

```json
{"Icao":"800B0A","Alt":15375,"GAlt":15278,"AltT":0,"Lat":10.579605,"Long":76.506561,"Mlat":false,"Spd":334.5,"Trak":26.3,"Vsi":832},{"Icao":"800463","Alt":3575,"GAlt":3445,"AltT":0,"Lat":40.626663,"Long":-74.261963,"Mlat":false,"Spd":274.4,"Trak":316.2,"Vsi":1472},
```